# How to replace values of a column based on another data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column containing symbols of chemical elements and other substances. Something like this:

| Commoditie |
| --- |
| sn |
| sulfuric acid |
| cu |
| sodium chloride |
| au |

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['sn', 'sulfuric acid', 'cu', 'sodium chloride', 'au'], columns=['Commodities'])
```

And I have another data frame containing the symbols of the chemical elements and their respective names. Like this:

| Name | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| sn | tin |
| cu | copper |
| au | gold |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['tin', 'copper', 'gold'], 'Symbol': ['sn', 'cu', 'au']})
```

I need to replace the symbols (in the first dataframe)(df1['Commoditie']) with the names (in the second one) (df2['Names']), so that it outputs like the following:

I need the
Output:

| Commoditie |
| --- |
| tin |
| sulfuric acid |
| copper |
| sodium chloride |
| gold |

I tried using for loops and lambda but got different results than expected. I have tried many things and googled, I think it's something basic, but I just can't find an answer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

first, convert df2 to a dictionary:

```
replace_dict=dict(df2[['Symbol','Name']].to_dict('split')['data'])
#{'sn': 'tin', 'cu': 'copper', 'au': 'gold'}
```

then use replace function:

```
df1['Commodities']=df1['Commodities'].replace(replace_dict)
print(df1)
'''
       Commodities
0              tin
1    sulfuric acid
2           copper
3  sodium chloride
4             gold
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1.Commodities = df1.Commodities.str.replace(row.Symbol, row.Name)
```

which gives `df1` as:

```
       Commodities
0              tin
1    sulfuric acid
2           copper
3  sodium chloride
4             gold
```

EDIT: Note that it's very likely to be far more efficient to skip defining `df2` at all and just `zip` your lists of names and symbols together and iterate over that.

Comment: A note, **iterrows** is the worst and longest way to iterate over rows.  You can use **df.to_dict** instead of iterrows.

Comment: I'm aware. Just trying to work within the parameters of the problem and why I added the note about not defining `df2`....